# Filter array based on dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Say I have an array of json objects which looks like below:

```
var codes = [{
            "code_id": "1",
            "code_name": "code 1",            ,
             }, {
            "code_id": "2",
            "code_name": "code889",

             },
        // ... () ...    
             ]
```

How can I filter codes array based on dynamic input parameter?

So I am looking for a generic function which will take input array and key and value as i/p.

```
var filteredCodes = getFilteredCodes(codes, "code_id", 2);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out the result - see demo below:

```js
var codes = [{"code_id": "1","code_name": "code 1"}, {"code_id": "2","code_name": "code889"}];

function getFilteredCodes(array, key, value) {
  return array.filter(function(e) {
    return e[key] == value;
  });
}

var filteredCodes = getFilteredCodes(codes, "code_id", 2);

console.log(filteredCodes);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with the key and value.

```js
function getFilteredCodes(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(function (o) {
        return o[key] === value;
    });
}

var codes = [{ "code_id": "1", "code_name": "code 1", }, { "code_id": "2", "code_name": "code889" }],
    filteredCodes = getFilteredCodes(codes, "code_id", "2");

console.log(filteredCodes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or the function in an only line with arrow notation

```js
var codes = [{ "code_id": "1", "code_name": "code 1", }, { "code_id": "2", "code_name": "code889" }];
var getFilteredCodes = (array, key, value) => array.filter(x => x[key] === value);
var FilteredCodes = getFilteredCodes(codes, "code_id", "2");
console.log(FilteredCodes);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getFilteredCodes(poolArray,key,val){
    return poolArray.filter(function(item,ind){
        return item[key]==val;
    });
}
```